# I'm getting an error "object Installs not found"?

Tags: r

```
library(dplyr)
playstore <- read.csv("googleplaystore.csv")

str(playstore)      
class(playstore)

playstore <- tbl_df(playstore)

head(playstore)

class(Installs)
```

Comment: From this code, the only first instance of Installs is when attempting to find its class. Did you mean `class(playstore$Installs)`?

Comment: @NelsonGon Actually, I was trying to filter the Apps with Installs done more than 10000 - filter(select(playstore, App, Installs, Rating), Installs < 10000)                                           but I'm getting a new error now -> In Ops.factor(Installs, 10000) : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors                                                                                                                                      I've changed the data type of "Installs" to numeric from factors too.

Comment: We can't help you efficiently because your problem does not include a reproducible example. It seems like the `Installs` column is read as factors (presumably because it has non numeric looking rows) but we can't be sure because we don't have access to your file

Comment: Add sample data,expected output and/or current output and code to your question. Use `dput(head(playstore))` and add that to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Created some dummy data and suggested solution.

```
library(tidyverse)
playstore<-data.frame(AppName=c("DBC","BCD","ECD"),Installs=c(1500,250,100))
playstore %>% 
  mutate(Installs=as.numeric(Installs),AppName=as.factor(AppName)) %>% 
  filter(Installs>1000)
```

This yields:

```
 AppName Installs
1     DBC     1500
```

Comment: Feel free to accept it as an answer if you feel it helped, cheers!